# bin packing with constraints?

Tags: combinatorics

I recently implemented a bin packing algorithm to help me decide how to re-balance some collections in my database cluster. I was very excited to see it balance all the collections by size as I wanted, but the way it fills bins places large collections together and then the last bin is full of tiny collections.

For example

```
BIN 1    BIN 2         BIN N
-----    -----   ....  -----  
500GB    500GB         0.07GB
200GB    200GB         0.06GB
100GB    100GB         .....
```

It would be more optimal for me if I could have bins that sought to maximize the number of small collections per large collection in each bin. Something like this:

```
BIN 1    BIN 2         BIN N
-----    -----   ....  -----  
500GB    500GB         200GB
100GB    100GB         200GB
0.76GB   0.76GB        0.76GB
...      ...           ...
```

The reason being that the large collections and small collections of complimentary usage patterns; by pairing them together I can more efficiently use my resources.

Comment: Just of the top, I would try putting the largest collection into the bin with the largest available space. Continuing for all collections. This should result in your second distribution.